# Autoload function typo3 7.6

Tags: typo3, autoload, typo3-7.6.x

How to call a class into my extension using autoload. I am using typo3 7.6. From the tutorials I understood that, for typo3 7.6, this can be done in ext_emconf.php file. How to write the same in ext_emconf.php??
 My class file is in Classes/class.x.php.

Answer (score 4):

All classes are automatically registered in an autoload function as long as you follow the code conventions:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/a-CodingGuidelines/Index.html

class.x.php is not a valid filename for a class in `Extbase`. If you want to create a ClassX then the filename has to be:

/your_extension/Classes/ClassX.php

```
<?php

namespace YourName\YourExtension;

class ClassX {

}
```

Note that the extension name also turns in UpperCamelCase. For the vendor part (YourName in the example) you can chose anything that is valid in PHP.

now you can access you class with

```
$test = new \YourName\YourExtension\ClassX();
```

Your extension obviously needs to be installed to work.

!!! Keep in mind, that Typo3 only generates the autoload cache when you install / uninstall an extension. If you add new files to an already installed extension you have to delete this cache file manually

```
/typo3temp/autoload/autoload_classmap.php
```

To configurate autoloading of classes that do no match the default naming you can create an `ext_autoload.php` in your extension. Inside the code looks like that:

```
<?php

return array(
    'Tx_SomeExtension_Someclass' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::extPath('some_extension') . 'pi1/someclass.php',
);
```

If you are developing for Typo3 7.x, keep in mind that pibased is outdated and is only supported with the compatibility extension that brings a lot of drawbacks in performance. I would recommend not to use pibased extension any more.

Comment: It was really helpfull. But I am bit confused about, how to write autoload function into my extension's ext_emconf.php file. From a tutorial I found that,   'autoload' => 
  array(
    'classmap' => array('Classes')
  ),  autoload function has to be written in this form.. But what is this classmap? Is it my classname, ClassX??

Comment: My extension is dependent on three other extensions, which are in pibase. So my task is to develop new classes into these and has to call these classes into my extension which is in extbase. Could you please help me ?

Comment: i have updated my post with an example of an autoload file

Comment: The compatibility fixed version of the pi base extension is used. Shall I write the autoload function in my extension or in compatibility fixed pibase extension?  Shall I write a namespace to the class file in the compatibility fixed pibase extension so that I can call it in the controller of my extbase extension?

Comment: autoload configuration always should be in the extension they belong to (so in the extensions you depend on). If that are public extensions from the repository, then it is a bad practice to overwrite its code because you can not update these extensions anymore, so you could put it inside your own extension.

Comment: I am getting an error as "Class Aa\Bb\Cc not found". I will explain what I've done. In the extension which is compatibility fixed version of pibase  extension, I had created a classes folder and in it a classfile AaBbCc.php with contents <?php
namespace Aa\Bb;
class AaBbCc {
 public function returnsTrue() {
  return true; }
}?>And into my extbase extension's controller I tried to call this class as  public function __construct() {
 $var = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance("Aa\Bb\Cc");
} In the frontend the error class not found occured. How to solve this?

Comment: Like i have described before, you have to either put the classes in the proper directory structure or create an autoload file. Since the name of the file does not fit the proper naming conventions you have to create the autoload file.